# combo box acting like a text box in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a combo box and drop down items are coming like:

```
<select name="combo1" id="combo1">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

But i want that this above combo box should behave like a **textbox** when user has not put mouse cursor on that combo box. But when user will put the cursor on that textbox, immediately that **textbox** will behave like a combo box(like above combo) and drop down items will come. How is it possible? Any help

Comment: once check this jquery autocomplete plugin :http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: no no user will not type anything, by simply putting the cursor on that textbox, it will behave like a combobox and user will select item from that combo box.

Comment: you can customise the above one like onfocus you could need to enable autocomplete..

Comment: i am trying but it is not happening, can you please show me a demo in a fiddle?

Comment: once check the below code and fiddle tom..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the autocomplete onfocus of input tag:

**html code:**

```
<div class="demo">  
    <div class="ui-widget">    
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>    
    <input id="tags">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function() {       
    var availableTags = [       
        "ActionScript",        
        "AppleScript",      
        "Asp",           
        "BASIC",          
        "C",        
        "C++",          
        "Clojure",    
        "COBOL",   
        "ColdFusion",    
        "Erlang",       
        "Fortran",    
        "Groovy",     
        "Haskell",  
        "Java",       
        "JavaScript",      
        "Lisp",        
        "Perl",         
        "PHP",        
        "Python",      
        "Ruby",         
        "Scala",        
        "Scheme"         ];     
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({          
        source: availableTags,
        minLength: 0
    }).focus(function(){            
            $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
        });
});
```

**For Reference:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Tpz2X/

Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: ya i got it but can you please help me by providing the js libraries and css libraries.

Comment: Which js and css libraries tom? and Increase your acceptance rating :-)

Comment: you have done it in the fiddle, so only jquery library is sufficient? for designing how can i import css files? you have not written any css code in fiddle.

Comment: you can use your own css or else please look into the  url for default library nad css: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: just one help needed can you please give the url of those files where i can find .css files for your above fiddle?

Comment: tom am not using any css there am just using autocomplete js which i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

U can use javascript for that.
Handle the event `OnMouseOver` of javascript and at this time enable your combo.
unless event did not take place disable it and when `OnMouseOver` event occurs enable it.